# Как с помощью SQLAlchemy сложить числа?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

У меня есть таблица, где в одной из ячеек хранится значение, которое отображает количество отправленных денег.

На данный момент написал вот такую функцию:

```
async def add_donations(_user_id, danation):
    _session_maker: sessionmaker = session_maker
    async with _session_maker() as session:
        async with session.begin():
            await session.execute(update(User).where(User.user_id ==_user_id).values(donations=danation))
```

В то время, как писал эту функцию, уже понимал, что она сможет только перезаписывать уже существующее значение.
Поэтому, вопрос. Каким образом нужно переделать функцию, чтобы она прибавляла к старому значению - новое